# problem with npm install - in laravel project

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, node-modules

After running `npm install` I'm facing below error.

```
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....1","requirejs":"^2.1'
```

composer.json file

```
 "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
```

package.json file

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try these steps and share your results:
Problem solved step by step:
1. npm cache clean –force
2. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
3. npm install

Comment: Hello,BABAK ASHRAFI
  After running npm cache clean                                                                            $ npm cache clean –force
npm ERR! npm cache clear does not accept arguments

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arafat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-24T06_36_46_021Z-debug.log

Comment: Have you run this? `npm cache clean --force `

Comment: Yes , I run this command and after that it shows above error.